# Is it possible to search elements in the Chrome debugger?

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, search

For example if I go to

> View -> Developer -> Developer Tools

and open up the `Elements Tab` is there a way to search with in these elements.

Here is an example URL that I want to do a search on:

https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1229340/

Using Control F pulls up a search box but it is for the actual web page not the debugger tab.

**Update**

So strange that it is working now

However, search results for `<title>` lists 3 found, but only shows 2:

- Anchorman 2: The Legend Continues (2013) - IMDb
- TryIMDbProFree

What is the 3rd  ?

Comment: I have tried and no problem with this, go to Elements tab and you can search any elements.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Click in the Elements Window Tab (green) and hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, the search bar will appear (red).  This will search for text and/or elements.

[image]

Comment: must have been a blip ... is working now ... how many results did you get for <title>, I got 3 but can not see the last one.

Comment: @JamieSiminoff on what page?

Comment: The example page I posted has 3 tiles but I can only see 2 ... https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1229340/

Comment: How many titles do you get and what are they.  Updated question to reflect.